# SSH SFTP Sampler

Tags: ssh, jmeter, sftp

Actually we have successfully done the configuration for SSH SFTP Sampler in JMeter and it's showing green in JMeter response sample result but no response code is shown for the same and XML file is also not reflecting in the respective DB.
Could anyone help me out in this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9SY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "anyone could help you out with this issue" because your screenshot doesn't tell the full story.

I don't know what "response code for the same" you're expecting, if you want to ensure that the file is there - just add [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) plugin to list the file(s) in the target directory using [`ls` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) before the uploading and the same after uploading

[image]

If you're uploading the file to a remote host - make sure to use `put` action.

[image]

Be informed that SFTP sampler uploads the file to the server over [SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/), the fact of the successful upload doesn't mean that the file will be "reflected in the respective DB"

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still facing the same issue as I have added SSH Command in my Test Plan but facing an error like '''cp is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file" in response of JMeter. My Test Scenario is to move or copy a SFTP XML file from a local machine (Windows) to the remote server location folder (Windows) via VPN. So Please share which command has to be used or any test plan related to that.

Comment: Source Path: E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\0072VENREGREQ23032021410.xml; Detination Path:D:\CPSMS_BANK_INTEGRATION\Local_Receive_Locations\REAT_TestReceiveLocation

Comment: I have checked by passing a command in cmd even in my local machine and it's working fine but when I am trying to use the same command in SSH command sampler...it's not showing any result in jmeter.

Comment: Could you please share of scp command syntax including remote username, host and password?

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
I would like to explain here that my both SFTP Servers are on Windows platform.
One thing is that when I am trying to pass the same command through cmd (Command Prompt) then it's working fine. SFTP file is moved successfully and also reflected in Database as well.
But when I am using JMeter SSH Command and SSH SFTP Sampler(s) to perform the same scenario by giving the exact path then it's not working and JMeter is not showing any result(s) as well.
Please help me to do the same.